# Dynamically created HTML id's, how to use eval when compare?

Tags: javascript

I create some dynamic ID checkboxes in the function `listInPorts`, and try to use `eval` in the function `checkports` doing comparisons to see if they are checked. I probably misunderstood how to use `eval` because it will not pass.

```
function listInPorts() {
  console.log("listInPorts()");
  var x = 0; portstring = "<table border='1' bgcolor=cyan width='199'>";
  inputs = mid.inputs.values();
  //List ports in and out
  Lportin = mid.inputs.values();
  for (listinput = Lportin.next(); listinput && !listinput.done;
    listinput = Lportin.next()) {
    var deviceIn = listinput.value.name;
    var optin = document.createElement("option");
    optin.text = deviceIn;
    //document.getElementById("in_portsel").add(optin);
    portstring = portstring + "<tr><td align=right><b>" + optin.text + "<input 
    id = 'inBox"+x+"' type = 'checkbox' checked > </b></td > </tr> ";
    x++;
  }
  document.getElementById("ports").innerHTML = portstring + "</table>";
}
function checkInPorts(mid) {
  var x = 0;
  inputs = mid.inputs.values();
  for (var input = inputs.next(); input && !input.done; input =
    inputs.next()) {
    if (eval("document.getElementById.('inBox" + x + "').checked") == false) { }
    else if (eval("document.getElementById.('inBox" + x + "').checked") == true) { input.value.onmidimessage = onMIDIMessage; }
    x++;
    //input.value.onmidimessage = onMIDIMessage;
  }
}
```

I know code is working if I just open all ports and do not try to check if the checkboxes are checked. So it must be the `eval` transformation/creation of the string to variable that is non-functional.

Comment: DO NOT USE EVAL. It is basic string concatenation.

Comment: eval is evil. You will have to add unsafe-eval of your CSP to get rid off security alerts.

Comment: Why are you creating an `option` element? You don't append it to anything... Also, you have an extra period after `getElementById`. But, as others have said, there is no need for `eval` here.

Comment: You don't need eval that, it's rarely needed. Just use `document.getElementById('inBox" + x + "').checked` it will be the same `'inbox' + x` will return string that can be used as argument to `getElementById` but you have error remove extra dot after `getElementById.` that's syntax error.

Comment: Not sure what i did wrong but i do need eval, here is the solution.

function checkInPorts(mid){
  var x=0;
  inputs = mid.inputs.values();
  for (var input = inputs.next(); input && !input.done; input = inputs.next()) {
   varString="document.getElementById('inBox"+x+"').checked";
   console.log("********"+varString);
   var myVar = eval(varString);
   if(myVar==false){  }
   else if(myVar==true){ input.value.onmidimessage = onMIDIMessage;  }
   x++;
  }
}

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using eval for basic element look ups?

```
if (document.getElementById('inBox' + x).checked) {
  console.log(x, "It is checked")
} else {
  console.log(x, "It is not checked")
}
```

Comment: Please correct your quotation mistake (use either single or double quotes in the first line).

Comment: @SparkFountain you have the ability to edit it too ;)

Comment: Yep, but only if I change at least six characters and I don't want to add or remove unnecessary stuff.

Comment: Because what you have does not match what I have. You have `myVar=document.getElementById('inBox "+ x +" ')` which is saying your id is `'inBox "+ x +" '` not `inBox1`

Comment: Not sure what i did wrong but i do need eval, here is the solution.

function checkInPorts(mid){
  var x=0;
  inputs = mid.inputs.values();
  for (var input = inputs.next(); input && !input.done; input = inputs.next()) {
   varString="document.getElementById('inBox"+x+"').checked";
   console.log("********"+varString);
   var myVar = eval(varString);
   if(myVar==false){  }
   else if(myVar==true){ input.value.onmidimessage = onMIDIMessage;  }
   x++;
  }
}

Comment: eval is never the solution. Again, you are using a string which makes NO sense. The problem is you using strings. Code above should work 100% fine inside the loop.